# Import Error for module that pip reports as installed

Tags: python, python-2.7, cygwin, pip

I'm trying to run a script using the backport of `Enum` for python 2.7.8, through Cygwin.

When the script is run, it outputs the generic error of `Import Error: No module named Enum`.

- `pip-2.7 install enum34` says that it's already installed
- `pip-2.7 install enum34 --upgrade` gave the same error
- `python --version` shows 2.7.8
- `pip freeze` shows `enum=1.0.4`
- `pip uninstall enum34 / pip install enum34` produced no difference

What can I try next?

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit confusing, but you need to import from `enum`, not `enum34`:

Here's an example from [the docs](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34):

```
from enum import Enum
class Color(Enum):
    red = 1
    green = 2
    blue = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't paste your code, but I'm guessing that you wrote

`import Enum`

with a capital E.  Try again with a lower-case "e":

`import enum`

Comment: Hm, I have `from enum import Enum` -- this works on other machines.